# rails 3, on heroku, how query for either of 2 different values in one field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to find all messages where the .user field is either of two values.

.user is a string

```
   @msgs = Foo.find :all, 
      :order => 'created_at ASC', 
      :conditions => [ "(user = ?) OR (user = ?)", @user1, @user2]
```

this query, on heroku (postgres) always returns empty

running locally, it returns data as expected.

Why does this not work? I'm absolutely positive the values in @user1 and @user2 do match data in the .user field because when I remove the conditions then filter in the VIEW using those same variable names it works fine.

Comment: Can you post some logs from dev and Heroku please?

Comment: unfortunately there's nothing to post, I logged @msgs.inspect after doing the find() and it just shows empty [] on Heroku and all the matching records on dev (sqllite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is postgres apparently does not like having a field named 'user' when I changed the fieldname it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps case sensitivity is the issue? I believe postgres is case-sensitive by default.

Try

```
 :conditions => [ "UPPER(user) = UPPER(?) OR UPPER(user) = UPPER(?)", @user1, @user2]
```

Comment: No, the data is a numeric string such as "123456789"